# If my ServiceBroker target "listener" calls end conversation, does it delete any messages added since it picked up the current message?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012, service-broker

I have a ServiceBroker for SQL Server. The sender "initiator" is in a trigger on `INSERT` on a table. It can be called very often and could happen multiple times during the target's reading/handling of a message.

In Microsoft's docs it states:

> When a conversation ends, Service Broker removes all messages for the conversation from the service queue.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177521.aspx

What does it consider a "conversation"? Is it simply that one message? Or if the trigger gets called again before the target ended the conversation, and adds another message, will that message also be deleted?

Target runs like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyTypeProcessed]
AS
DECLARE @ConversationHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @MessageType NVARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @MessageBody XML
DECLARE @ResponseMessage XML
DECLARE @strMessageBody NVARCHAR(MAX)

WHILE(1=1)
    BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    WAITFOR(RECEIVE TOP(1)
    @ConversationHandle = conversation_handle,
    @MessageType = message_type_name,
    @MessageBody = CAST(message_body AS XML)
    FROM
    MyTypeTargetQueue
    ), TIMEOUT 1000
    IF(@@ROWCOUNT=0)
        BEGIN
        RETURN
        END
    SELECT @MessageType
    IF @MessageType = 'MyTypeRequest'
        BEGIN
        SET @strMessageBody = cast(@MessageBody as nvarchar(Max));
        EXEC SP_HandleMessage @strMessageBody
        --Close the conversation on the Payment Service
        END CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH
    END
GO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A conversation in service broker is anything identified by the same conversation handle. So what's a conversation handle? When you start a dialog, you issue a statement like this:

```
declare @ch uniqueidentifier;
begin dialog @ch
   from service [foo]
   to service 'bar'
   on contract [YourContract];
```

In this example, `@ch` is the conversation handle. Any messages you send between the initiator and the target (and vice versa) for that conversation will use that identifier. Both the initiator or the target may send as many messages as they want (that is, it's not limited to a "one request/one response" paradigm).

Pairing your quote from the documentation with the next line from the same documentation:

> After a conversation ends, an application can no longer send or receive messages for that conversation.

It indicates that for this side of the conversation, all activity is considered done. As a result, any messages left in the queue for this conversation are discarded. When the `END CONVERSATION` statement is issued, a message is put onto the queue for the other side to process. But it will process it in order received. That is, if there is a backlog of messages on the other side of the dialog, they will be processed until the end dialog message is processed.